# Accessing Derived class members in base class method

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I have a peculiar requirement and not been able to find a solution.

```
class Base
{
public:
    void func()
    {
       //access the member say 'var' of derived class
    }
}
```

1. It is mandatory in our case that all derived class from base will have member 'var'.
2. Name of the derived class can be anything.

Comment: Why not have the `var` in the `Base` as it is common to all derived?

Comment: There is a always a better solution to your source of "peculiar" requirement. Instead of breaking the fundamental tenets of object oriented programming look deeper at why you have such a requirement and ways of solving it with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 9):

Since all `var`s in the derived classes will need to be of the same type to even make any sense, why not simply but it in the base class?

```
class Base
{
public:
    void func()
    {
      // use var
    }
protected: // allow derived classes to access 'var'
           // and give it a value on construction
    // where T == whatever type you want
    Base(T v) : var(v){}
    T var; 
};
```

Comment: I considered this, but we don't want to implement it this way

Comment: This is exactly how this should be implemented, at least based on what the OP has stated.

Comment: @HellBoy: Please continue this phrase: We don't want to implement it this way, because ...

Comment: Then maybe he should write the implementation? Can you ask him for reasons why he doesn't want that? I can't believe that someone would just say "we won't do it that way, and I'm not telling why!"

Comment: @HellBoy: Please slap your manager. I can't see any reason to *not* do this.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic clearly you have not dealt with managers, they are 'experts' don't you know

Comment: @thecoshman :)  true, but this is extremely strange. Usually they at least pretend to have reasons

Comment: I think it is about "dependency inversion".

Comment: @phresnel: So instead of the derived class depending on the base class, the base class should depend on the derived class? [What.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FlatWhat) Doesn't this, like, subvert every teaching of OO *ever*?

Answer (score 6):

You'll need a `virtual` function that returns that member:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void func()
    {
       getVar();
    }
    virtual int getVar() = 0;
};
class Derived : public Base
{
    int var;
    virtual int getVar() { return var; }
};
```

A better design would be having `var` in the base class, since it's a common member. Otherwise, C++ doesn't have any reflection mechanism, so dynamically inspecting classes the way you'd want is out of the question.

Comment: The use of `getVar()` could be a better method because the value would be somewhat guaranteed to be updated.

Comment: @MarkGarcia It is unclear to me what you are trying to _add_ with your comment